# Proving that in the real line being an interval is equivalent to being connected

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Theorem.** A subset $E$ of the real line is connected if and only if it is an interval.

I’m reading Rudin’s mathematical analysis and I’m trying to prove the theorems by myself before reading the proofs in the book. So I want to check if my proof of the converse of this theorem is correct:

**Proof of the Converse.** Suppose that $E$ is an interval. Toward a contradiction, suppose that $E$ is not connected. Hence $E=A\cup B$ for two nonempty separated sets $A,B$. Let $x\in A, y\in B$ and suppose $x\lt y$. Let $z$ be the supremum of the set of all $a\in A$ such that $a\lt y$. Since $z$ lies in the closure of $A$, it does not lie in $B$. Moreover, as $E$ is an interval it must contain $z$, which implies $z\in A$.

Now, $(z,y)$ can’t contain any elements of $A$ according to the definition of $z$. Therefore the whole $(z,y)$ must lie in $B$ (since $E$ is an interval). But it implies that $z$ which lies in $A$ also lies in the closure of $B$, that is, $A$ and $B$ are not separated.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: @Prasiortle thank you

Comment: You're welcome!